# Ongoing (recursive) publish/subscribe tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, publish-subscribe

I am struggling with the various available API in `java.util.concurrent`.

I am writing an ATOM API crawler which does the following:

1. publish a first hyperlink to visit
2. take a link, mark it as visited, perform a GET request and parse the result as a Feed object
3. extract all unvisited links from the Feed object and publish them
4. go to 2.

The visited status is stored in an in-memory database.
I have first written a single-threaded recursive implementation based on two combined functions (for point 1 and 2). 
This is of course very inefficient.

What I would like to achieve is having several worker threads within the same JVM, each turning an input link into published output links *until exhaustion of links* (i.e. all links are visited).

The fact that those workers are both consumer and produced confuse me a lot, I'm not sure whether I should pick a `BlockingQueue`, a `ExecutorCompletionService` or something else (preferably from the JDK, not from a 3rd-party lib).

I unsuccessfully tried the two first options.

Thanks for your help,
Rolf

Comment: Seems like it would be pretty simple to just use ExecutorService.execute().  If the tasks are responsible for scheduling new sub-tasks and storing the results, you don't have to involve futures.

Comment: But the producers produce links faster than consumer (in this case themselves) can consume. How will this work a simple ExecutorService? (Sorry for the current confusion)

Comment: An executor service normally consists of a pool of threads and a queue.  Those resources are managed for you so you don't have to worry about them.  You submit tasks to the queue by calling ExecutorService.execute() or submit().  As long as you have enough memory to hold all of the enqueued tasks, there should be no problem.  In your case, the scheduled tasks should not consume a lot of memory, as each one just needs to have a string or uri object representing the link to visit.

Comment: *"Infinite publish/subscribe tasks"* This is your requirement or problem statement? *"What I would like to achieve is having several worker threads within the same JVM, each turning an input link into published output links until exhaustion of links (i.e. all links are visited)."* Do you need one set of threads doing one thing and another set of things something else?

Comment: Nothing is infinite, but exactly how many links do you expect to follow?  If the queue of links can't fit in memory then you'll have to buffer them to disk.

Comment: @JimN : I don't mind blocking if the queue is full.

Comment: @hagrawal : I'm not sure. I just want a more efficient solution than the current sequential one. I feel this kind of computation is a good candidate for concurrency, that's all. I changed the title by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Following JimN's suggestion, this would be my pseudo-architecture:

```
// to avoid looping: keeps track of processed/processing URLs
ConcurrentMap<String, Boolean> visited = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
// initialize the executor with poolSize concurrent threads
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
// post first thread
try {
   for (;;) {
     pool.execute(new AtomRequest(startUrl));
   }
} catch (IOException ex) {
   pool.shutdown();
}

// the actual work is done in instances of this
class AtomRequest implements Runnable {
   private final String url;
   AtomRequest(String url) { this.url = url; }
   public void run() {
      if (visited.putIfAbsent(url, true)) {
          return; // already being processed: avoid loop
      }
      // download with 'get' request, and parse for new links
      // ...
      for (String u : outgoingUrls) {
          pool.submit(new AtomRequest(u)); // does not block
      }
   }
}
```

Missing is the download-and-parsing code, and the shutdown code (for when you get tired of crawling). You can find simple-but-working [shutdown code in the ExecutorService documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).